# Removing Item from List in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am having a little trouble understanding a snippet of code my professor shared with us in class:

```
takeout(X, [X|R], R).
takeout(X, [F|R], [F|S]) :- takeout(X,R,S)
```

The general idea of the code is to remove the element X. However, I am a little confused on why in the second code of line there are two parameters that both have F as its head. I also don't completely understand what the relation :- takeout(X,R,S) means in relation to the first part of the code in that line. I am wondering if this means there is some sort of loop taking place.

When I run the code with `?- takeout(a, [1,2,3,a,b,c,b], X)` I get the result X = [1,2,3,b,c,b] as expected. If anyone could help me better understand these 2 lines of code that would be greatly appreciated as I am new to prolog.

Comment: This is the same as [select/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=select/3) - you can see what's happening by [stepping through the code](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=debugger) using e.g. `trace` or `gtrace`.

Comment: don't overthink it. try running, tracing, and changing the code to understand why things are where they are. In addition, I am quite sure that this predicate is explained in detail in "The Art of Prolog" by Sterling & Shapiro, along with other related predicates; you can get the book from your library or download the PDF from the publisher for free.

Answer (score 2):

The first line is the base case of the predicate: if the first element on the original list is equal at the element you need to remove, the predicate is true only if the third argument is the rest of the list. The second line is the recursive step of the predicate. Due to Prolog execution order, it is tested only if the first element on the list is not equal to the element to remove. What the line says is: "The predicate takeout(X, [F|R], [F|S]) is true only if the predicate takeout(X,R,S) is true".  So the program goes on testing the predicate on the rest of the original list. It is important to say that the predicate will be false if there is no item to remove. If you don't wan't this particular thing to happen you need to add another base case: takeout(_, [], []).

Comment: There is some questionable stuff in your description. "if the first element on the original list is equal at the element you need to remove" no, if it **unifies**. "it is tested only if the first element on the list is not equal" not exactly true, try: `takeout(A, [X,Y], R)`. You should read the same textbook I suggested to OP.

Comment: Yeah my description was rather imprecise, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: "If you don't wan't this particular thing to happen you need to add another base case" - would be more deterministic [to use *->](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=*-%3E/2)

Answer (score 1):

Like most recursive problems, the problem of removing an item from a list has just a couple of cases:

1. The special/terminating case: The head of the list is the item to be removed. In which case, the list without the item to be removed is that tail of the list.
2. The general/recursive case: the head of the list is *not* the item to be removed. In which case, we add the head of the list to the result list and recurse down, passing the tails of both the source and result lists.

In your sample code:

```
takeout( X , [X|R] , R.    ) .
takeout( X , [F|R] , [F|S] ) :- takeout(X,R,S) .
```

The first clause is the special/terminating case, and the second, the general, recursive case.

However, it does not account for the empty list, or for lists that do not contain the item to be removed. You need an additional case:

```
takeout( _ , []    , []    ) .
takeout( X , [X|R] , R.    ) .
takeout( X , [F|R] , [F|S] ) :- takeout(X,R,S) .
```

In Prolog, there is in general a lot of *magick* that goes on in the heads of clauses. Your sample code could be restated to make what's happening in the heads of the clauses more explicit (and perhaps clarify what's going on):

```
take_out( _ , [].    , [] ) .  % Removing anything from the empty list yields the empty list.
take_out( X , [Y|Ys] , Zs ) :- % We can remove X from Ys...
  X  = Y  ,                    % - if X is [unifies with] the head of Ys, and
  Zs = Ys                      % - if Zs is [unifies with] the tail of Ys
  .                            % Easy!
take_out( X , [Y|Ys] , Zs ) :- % Alternatively, we can remove X from Ys if...
  X \= Y ,                     % - X is NOT (does not unify with) the head of Ys, and
  Zs = [Y|Z1] ,                % - Zs is a list with Y at its head, and
  take_out( X , Ys , Z1 )      % - we can [recursively] remove X from the tail of Ys, giving the tail of Zs
  .                            % - Also easy!
```